# Mongodump - command not found when executing dump

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to create a backup of my database using Mongodump. The problem is that every time i execute the dump, i get the following error:

```
--collection: command not found
```

Here is the command:

```
mongodump --uri=MYURI --collection TEST-COL --gzip --out=/var/backups/testbackup
```

I'm using linux, while on windows the same command seems to work. Any advice?

Comment: Have you specified the database in the URI?

Comment: Yes, my URI looks like this: mongodb://user:pass@ip:27017/?authSource=MYDB&replicaSet=replicaSetOne&readPreference=primary

Comment: It should be --collection=TEST-COL, you miss the equal (=) operator.

Comment: Yes, i tried with the = too but the output is the same, same error

Comment: Your password can have some special chars ...

Comment: Have you tried excluded the --collection? Do you get any other error?

Comment: try adding the --collection <name>  before the --uri

Comment: If i try without --collection i get the same erro but with gzip

Comment: This is weird. If i put --collection BEFORE the uri i get: Failed: bad option: cannot dump a collection without a specified database

Comment: Check that your URI is wrap with double quotes ( " "), use --db to specific database.

Comment: Indeed... the problem is that i was missing the double quotes

Comment: Good, I added the response so others can benefited to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [URI](https://docs.mongodb.com/database-tools/mongodump/#cmdoption-mongodump-uri) is a connection string, must be wrap with double quotes ("").

```
--uri=<connectionString>
```